# multiple canvases into a single div and combining them all into one canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I have dynamically created canvases being appended into a div. I have a mechanism that allows these canvases to be moved freely within the div.
 (each canvas is actually a dynamically rendered pictograph)

Now once user is done with adding the pictographs, i would like to publish that div on some social network in the form of image using the external APIs.

I researched and they say: you cannot export a div as an image. So i thought why not combine these canvases into one and then use canvas.todataurl()

Please point the kid in the right direction as i am new to html5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps to the solution :

- Compute the bouding box of all canvases.
- Create a new canvas of that size.
- Copy all canvases with the right offset on that canvas.
- retrieve the image using toDataUrl

Edit : Small explanation : the bounding box is just the rectangle that visually contains something.

Here we want the bounding box of all canvases -the smallest rect that contains all canvases - to know the size required to copy them all in a single canvas.

To get the bounding box of a canvas on the screen we use the magical getBoundingClientRect() : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect
it returns left, top, width, height of the rect that contains the html element.

So we start by taking the bounding box of the first canvas, and then we expand it with the bounding box of the second (adjusting left, top, or width or height ), etc, .. so at the end we have the bounding box of all canvases.

After we create the combination canvas, and just copy the canvases at their right place.

http://jsbin.com/eZiDUbo/1/

and the same with icons : http://jsbin.com/eZiDUbo/4/

[image]

```
  // compute bounding rect for all canvases :
  var globalRect  = canvasInfo[0].bcr; 
  // rect is read-only, let's change this :
  globalRect = { left : globalRect.left, top : globalRect.top, 
                  width : globalRect.width, height : globalRect.height };

  for (i=1; i<canvasCount; i++) {
    var  br = canvasInfo[i].bcr;
    expandRect(globalRect, br) ;
  }

  // create new canvas
  var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  newCanvas.width = globalRect.width ;
  newCanvas.height = globalRect.height ;
  var newCtx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

  // print all canvases on the new canvas
  for (i=0; i<canvasCount; i++) {
    var  cv = canvasInfo[i].cv;
    var br = canvasInfo[i].bcr ;
    newCtx.drawImage(cv, br.left - globalRect.left, br.top-globalRect.top);
  }

  document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
```

expand rect is like :

```
  // ----------------------------------
  // ----------------------------------

  // expands [rect] bounding rectangle with [nRect]. 
  // so that rect contains nRect.
  function expandRect (rect, nRect) {
    // check left
    if (nRect.left<rect.left) {
      rect.width +=     rect.left - nRect.left;
      rect.left=nRect.left;
    }
    // check top
    if (nRect.top<rect.top) {
      rect.height += rect.top - nRect.top ; 
      rect.top=nRect.top;  
    }
    // check right
    if ( ( nRect.left + nRect.width ) >  ( rect.left + rect.width ) ) {
      rect.width +=  ( nRect.left + nRect.width )- (rect.left + rect.width);      
    }
    // check bottom
    if ( (nRect.top + nRect.height) > (rect.top + rect.height ) ) {
      rect.height +=  (nRect.top + nRect.height) - (rect.top + rect.height ) ;      
    }  
  }
```

Comment: a quick question: is there a way we can use icons in html5 canvas? css based icons?

Comment: icons are just small images, so yep.

Comment: can you show a quick example of putting up a icon in canvas if its not of much botheration for you?

Comment: you have to be sure that images are loaded,Look here : http://jsbin.com/eZiDUbo/4/   Beware of same origin policy if the icons don't come from your site : toDataUrl will return an empty image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46602/discussion-between-benerd-and-gamealchemist)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a canvas which will contain the combined layers. Then, from each layer, you have to use [`context.getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29) and put the result in the final canvas using [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#putImageData%28%29).

Finally, use `toDataUrl()` on the combined canvas.